# Match up date and time values in different Excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel file and need the following.
There are two sheets in one Excel file. The first sheet shows date and time values in column C & D. The second sheet does this too in column A & B.

I want to match up the date and time from sheet 1 with sheet 2 and when there is a match put column C (date) of sheet 2 in column G of sheet 1.

For example in sheet 1 cell C3 & D3 are "2/24/2009" & "15:00".  In sheet 2 that matches with A13 & B13 and so we take C13 from sheet 2 and place it in sheet 1 G3.

I want to be able to replace the cells in sheet 1 and sheet 2 and they should be able to repopulate with correct data.

Comment: What is wrong with `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: i have used excel for simple purposes before... i have no idea on how to do it...and I know nothing about Vlookup

Comment: Is there an error in your description? You say "we take C13 from sheet 2". But this isn't your date column. This is in column A of sheet 2, or not? Anyway, with the solution below you could retrieve any column. So edit just the *index number*.

Comment: no it is not an error....there is one another column in sheet 2 (it is column 'C' ) that has some values corresponding to columns A & B....
for ex... 
 A              B            C
(date)       (time)        (views)

so i need to transfer or import values from the cells of this "C" column to those rows in sheet 1, that have same values in columns "A" & "B" asin sheet 2....

and i want that new column in sheet 1 to be "G"

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without changing the original data layout or joining any data. You can use an Index/Match combo like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10,MATCH(Sheet1!C2+Sheet1!D2,INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10+Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10,0),0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`=VLOOKUP`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13780/using-vlookup-in-excel/) together with two helper columns.

Syntax: `=VLOOKUP( value, table_array, index_number, [not_exact_match] )`

Since *VLOOKUP* can only compare a single column you need to join your two columns date and time in a single helper column:

1. In sheet 1 place this in column F and fill it down : `=C2 & "-" & D2`.
   This creates our helper column as you can see in the screenshot.
   Don't worry about the wrong time format at the end.

   [image]
2. In sheet 2 you have to insert a new empty column A so your date and time columns shifts one column to the right.

   Its important for VLOOKUP that the value to search is in the first column of your search table in sheet 2.  So this time we use column A in sheet 2 to create our helper column.

   Place this in your empty column A of sheet 2 and fill it down : `=B3 & "-" & C3` again.
3. Now we are ready to use VLOOKUP. Insert this formula in sheet 1 column G and fill it down.
   `=VLOOKUP(F2,sheet2!$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)`

   This will search the value from sheet 1 cell F2 in the first column of sheet 2 column A.
   After a match, it returns the value of your desired column from your sheet 2 table. In your example it should be column D (remember the shift)

   [image]

**Additional cosmetic improvements**

- To hide mismatches (#NA) you can use [a combination of =IF, =ISNA and your VLOOKUP formula.](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)
  `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2,sheet2!$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(F2,sheet2!$A$2:$D$4,4,FALSE))`